# Ignore task exception in ContinueWith

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, continuewith

I want to suppress exception triggered in the task. As I recall, some time ago I used this code to make it possible:

```
void Main(..)
{
    Task Fail()
    {
        throw new Exception("ex");
    }

    Fail().ContinueWith(t => 
        { 
            var ignored = t.Exception;
            ignored?.Handle(e => true);
        },
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted |
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
}
```

I see that when I run this in Console application (.NET 6) now, the only logic happens is making thrown exception (`t.Exception`) "observed" and then, this actually triggered exception is being pushed to the main method (outside task) and crashes my application.

Adding `await` like:

```
await (Fail().ContinueWith(..))
```

doesn't make difference.

I'm not sure why I remember it worked before, but any ideas how to make this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explain on my blog, [all `async` methods begin executing synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). The `async` keyword transforms your method into a state machine, including code that catches thrown exceptions and places them on the returned task. Without the `async` keyword, the method is just like any other method, and the exception is thrown directly.

To fix, add the `async` keyword:

```
async Task Fail()
{
  throw new Exception("ex");
}
```

Comment: This will create a compilation warning about an `async` method that lacks `await`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't await `Fail()` method at the beginning. It runs before you chain with with `ContinueWith` method. If you add some delay to beginning, like few hundred milliseconds, you will see that your code is working;

```cs
async Task Fail()
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    
    throw new Exception("ex");
}

await Fail().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    var ignored = t.Exception;
    ignored?.Handle(e => true);
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception Handled: {t.Exception.Message}");
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
```

But to prevent that and not use that dirty "trick" to solve your "problem", you need to use `Task.Run()` method and chain it with `ContinueWith` method;

```cs
Task Fail()
{
    throw new Exception("ex");
}

await Task.Run(Fail).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    var ignored = t.Exception;
    ignored?.Handle(e => true);
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception Handled: {t.Exception.Message}");
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
```

If you want to keep your `Main()` method `void`, instead of making it `async Task Main()`, remove the `await` keyword and add these two methods to the end of `ContinueWith` method;

```cs
GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the `Fail()` method fails to create a `Task`, and instead it throws synchronously an exception. The `.ContinueWith` is irrelevant. A continuation is never attached to a `Task`, because a `Task` was never created in the first place. You can't suppress exceptions triggered in a task, if you don't have a `Task` to begin with.

In order to suppress synchronous exceptions thrown by method calls, the most primitive tool to use is the [`try`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements#the-try-statement) statement with an empty `catch` block:

```
try { Fail(); } catch { }
```

Comment: this is true, I had to carefully check what actually happens and notice that `ContinueWith`  is even not called. What I have provided is just a single use case I have, so simple try/catch is not the best option to me considering other not mentioned goals.

Comment: @Unnamed you could consider posting a new question, presenting a more representative example of your actual case. Because the example you presented here is definitely best solved with a simple `try`/`catch` block.